# How to properly use ResolveAssemblyReference build task in VisualStudio/MSBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, twilio, msbuild-task

After adding a reference to Twilio REST API library to one of our core libraries we lost RestSharp.dll from output folder. We think the reason for that is the conflict between version of RestSharp.dll that Twilio and other DLL use.

What is the right way to configure ResolveAssemblyReference task so we get an error during build time and not a silently missing DLL ?

Project structure:

```
Main project (website)
    Twilio.dll
        RestSharp.dll 105.x.x.x
    OtherAPI.dll
        RestSharp.dll 104.x.x.x
```